# Delphi callbacks?

Tags: delphi, function, callback, procedure

I would like to know if it's possible to implement something like this:

`procedure waitandcall(time,@MyProcedureOrFunction)`

which execute the function or procedure I've created ?

I'm not sure if they are called callbacks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's absolutely possible, and you don't even need @ before your function.

In fact, all the events are based on this.

Start by defining a type for your function/procedure

```
type
  TMyProc = procedure(Param1: Integer);
```

Then you can use your procedure type anywhere, as long as your procedure's signature matches your type.

If you're using an object method instead of a plain procedure/function, you need to use `of object`

```
type
  TMyMethod = procedure(Param1: Integer) of object;
```

To call your callback from within, you can use something like this:

```
procedure DoAndCallBack(MyProc: TMyProc)
begin
  MyProc(1);
end;
```

Comment: Just added an example on how you can use the callback.

Comment: If I understand this mean i could pass any procedures ?

Comment: As long as the declaration is the same (same parameters, same return type, same calling convention), yes.

Comment: Could not use this with stdcall

Answer (score 5):

*Callbacks* are exactly what those are called, and Delphi is entirely capable of both creating and calling them. They are also known as *function pointers*. See [*Procedural Types*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Procedural_Types) in the documentation.

Comment: Do you have an example how to use them properly? I mean what I need to write inside the waitandcall function to execute the procedure?

Comment: If it does what its name suggests, you can do it in two  instructions: `Sleep(t); F;`

Comment: Basically i wanted a "blocking" procedure (for a thread) which count time (gettickcount) and wait (sleep) then launch whatever procedure

Comment: Oh well you just made me realized that I've overthinked a little bit... just sleep(x amount of time)